# Remove part of breadcrumb from category and product page

Tags: magento-1.7, product, catalog, breadcrumbs

I added an extra category but i don't want to show this in the breadcrumb.

I searched for a while how i can remove a part from it and found the following solution:

In `app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Breadcrumbs.php` I added the following code:

```
function removeCrumb($crumbName) {
    if ((!isset($this->_crumbs[$crumbName])) || (!$this->_crumbs[$crumbName]['readonly'])) {
    unset($this->_crumbs[$crumbName]);
}
    return $this;
}
```

Then ,i added the following code in `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php` after

`$this->getLayout()->createBlock(‘catalog/breadcrumbs’);`

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->removeCrumb('home');
```

Instead of 'home' I can use the `word category + the id of the category to remove this part from the breadcrumbs.`

This all works fine, but unfortunately only on the product page. When I try to do the same in `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category/View.php` something strange happens:

instead of '`home - cat1 - cat2`' it becomes '`home - cat2 - cat1'`.

No idea why.

Does someone knows how to solve this problem for the category page?

I'm using magento 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be wiser to rewrite the `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data`, as it provides the data on what categories will be added to breadcrumbs.

Assuming you know how to rewrite that helper class, here's what you have to do:

1. Rewrite the class `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data`.
2. Override `getBreadcrumbPath` method.
3. Copy the original method but modify these lines:

   ```
   // add category path breadcrumb
   foreach ($pathIds as $categoryId) {
       if (isset($categories[$categoryId]) && 
           $categories[$categoryId]->getName() &&
           $categoryId != $YOUR_CATEGORY_ID // Notice the extra category check here...
       ) {
           $path['category'.$categoryId] = array(
               'label' => $categories[$categoryId]->getName(),
               'link' => $this->_isCategoryLink($categoryId) ? $categories[$categoryId]->getUrl() : ''
           );
       }
   }
   ```

Replace `$YOUR_CATEGORY_ID` variable or set a value for it.

EDIT:

#### In case you don't know how to do a class rewrite

1. Open the file `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data`.
2. Find the method `getBreadcrumbPath`. It starts with something like `public function getBreadcrumbPath()`
3. Replace the whole method with this code:

   ```
   public function getBreadcrumbPath()
   {
       if (!$this->_categoryPath) {

           $path = array();
           if ($category = $this->getCategory()) {
               $pathInStore = $category->getPathInStore();
               $pathIds = array_reverse(explode(',', $pathInStore));

               $categories = $category->getParentCategories();

               !$category_ids_to_remove = array(YOUR_CATEGORY_ID_1, YOUR_CATEGORY_ID_2);
               // add category path breadcrumb
               foreach ($pathIds as $categoryId) {
                   if (isset($categories[$categoryId]) && 
                       $categories[$categoryId]->getName() &&
                       !in_array($categoryId, $category_ids_to_remove) // Notice the extra category check here...
                   ) {
                       $path['category'.$categoryId] = array(
                           'label' => $categories[$categoryId]->getName(),
                           'link' => $this->_isCategoryLink($categoryId) ? $categories[$categoryId]->getUrl() : ''
                       );
                   }
               }
           }

           if ($this->getProduct()) {
               $path['product'] = array('label'=>$this->getProduct()->getName());
           }

           $this->_categoryPath = $path;
       }
       return $this->_categoryPath;
   }
   ```

Replace the text `YOUR_CATEGORY_ID` to the actual category ID of the category you want to hide. It should work after that.

Please take note that rewrite core classes is extremely not recommended as core files are replaced whenever you update your magento.

Comment: I would suggest creating an observer on Mage_Catalog_Block_Breadcrumbs::_preapareLayout() might be more adventageous so you don't have to rewrite the block.

Comment: But then in the head block, the title would contain the category that he does not want to display. It would be better to prevent it to be added in breadcrumb instead of removing it after.

Comment: @DouglasRadburn Thanks for the suggestion, by the way. Just to be clear, I'm suggesting that he would rewrite a helper, not a block.

Comment: To be honest; I have no idea how to do all this. I followed other instructions I found and came this far, but now I'm stuck.

Comment: I updated my answer hoping that it would help you... Magento might be too much for you to handle at your stage.

Comment: I have one more question, what if I would like to remove more than one category? For one category it works perfect, but I don't know how to remove more.

Comment: There, I updated my answer to suit your needs, replace `YOUR_CATEGORY_ID_1`, `YOUR_CATEGORY_ID_2`. You can add more by adding a comma(,) in between.