# Magento 2 : How to remove part of the breadcrumbs in category product page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, breadcrumbs

I have found [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72169/remove-part-of-breadcrumb-from-category-and-product-page) but it's for **Magento 1.7.**

I want to remove the product name in breadcrumb, so that my breadcrumbs will only show the category. For example, from:

```
Home/Category Name/Product Name
```

to:

```
Home/Category Name
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `after plugin` for method `getBreadcrumbPath()` of class `Data` in namespace `Magento\Catalog\Helper` and modify the `return array`.

You know more about plugins you can go through https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html